# Include all dependencies using dotnet pack

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, .net-core

Is there any way to force `dotnet pack` to include all referenced assemblies (all dependencies in project.json)?

I believe this is related:

- https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/1290
- https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3959

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As of 2020 there is no officially supported way to do this. However various people have come up with ways to achieve it, and the current best way is to install a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Teronis.MSBuild.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage/) prepared by the amazing [Teroneko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2788957/teroneko). Then all you need to do is edit your .csproj to update all your project to be flagged with `PrivateAssets="all"`, [as per the package README](https://github.com/teroneko/Teronis.DotNet/tree/develop/src/MSBuild/Packaging/ProjectBuildInPackage).

---

If you are unable to install the aforementioned NuGet package, you can achieve the same effect [by editing your `.csproj` to include the following](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3891#issuecomment-569491001) (once again, this was discovered by Teroneko - it's essentially what the NuGet package he created does):

```xml
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>$(TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput);CopyProjectReferencesToPackage</TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <Target Name="CopyProjectReferencesToPackage" DependsOnTargets="BuildOnlySettings;ResolveReferences">
    <ItemGroup>
      <!-- Filter out unnecessary files -->
      <_ReferenceCopyLocalPaths Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths->WithMetadataValue('ReferenceSourceTarget', 'ProjectReference')->WithMetadataValue('PrivateAssets', 'All'))"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <!-- Print batches for debug purposes -->
    <Message Text="Batch for .nupkg: ReferenceCopyLocalPaths = @(_ReferenceCopyLocalPaths), ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.DestinationSubDirectory = %(_ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.DestinationSubDirectory) Filename = %(_ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.Filename) Extension = %(_ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.Extension)" Importance="High" Condition="'@(_ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)' != ''" />

    <ItemGroup>
      <!-- Add file to package with consideration of sub folder. If empty, the root folder is chosen. -->
      <BuildOutputInPackage Include="@(_ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)" TargetPath="%(_ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.DestinationSubDirectory)"/>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

As with the package, you then mark the depended-upon project reference(s) in your .csproj with `PrivateAssets="all"`, and it Just Works(tm).

Comment: im trying this simply does not work... get the following issues on pipelines 

"
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
##[error]An error occurred while trying to pack the files.
"

Comment: +1 Works for me.  I have a solution containing an F# project and a C# wrapper for it (plus some other bits and bobs).  Before applying this solution (simple cut/paste) my `.nupkg` did not contain the F# DLL.  After applying this solution, it did.  Not sure why dependencies are not considered necessary by the `pack` command though.

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome, could be from me. :D ([Here](https://github.com/teroneko/Teronis.DotNet/tree/develop/src/MSBuild/Packaging/ProjectBuildInPackage) you find the source code of the lines above. I decided to deliver it as [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Teronis.MSBuild.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage/) too)

Comment: @Teroneko I had no idea you have an account here - I have updated the answer to include your package and also converted the answer to Community Wiki so that I do not get credit for it (I should have done so when I first posted it). If you want, you can post your own answer with a link to your package in order to get deserved reputation from people it helps - if you do so, I will flag this answer to be deleted so that yours is the canonical one.

Comment: Marking as correct, since there is still no way and probably never will be.

Comment: This doesn't work in combination with a `--no-build` flag (which is default behavior on AppVeyor) because it invokes a (re)build implicitly because of the `DependsOn`.
 `dotnet pack -c release -o pack --no-build` produces the error `error NETSDK1085: The 'NoBuild' property was set to true but the 'Build' target was invoked.`

Comment: `PrivateAssets="all"` was very confusing to me, but read it like this, **Include all private assets** in the NuGet package for the given project reference.

Answer (score 9):

Another solution to the problem is to create a custom .targets file to include in your projects. You can add some msbuild instructions to include the files that you need in the package. There is some [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#advanced-extension-points-to-create-customized-package) on how to do it, here a short example

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(PackAsComponent) != ''">
  <TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>$(TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput);CustomBuildOutput</TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>
  <TargetsForTfmSpecificContentInPackage>$(TargetsForTfmSpecificContentInPackage);CustomContentInPackage</TargetsForTfmSpecificContentInPackage>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="CustomBuildOutput">
  <ItemGroup>
    <BuildOutputInPackage Include="$(OutputPath)*.dll" Exclude="$(TargetPath)" />
    <BuildOutputInPackage Include="$(OutputPath)*.pdb" />
    <BuildOutputInPackage Include="$(OutputPath)*.exe" Exclude="$(TargetPath)" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>

<Target Name="CustomContentInPackage">
  <ItemGroup>
    <TfmSpecificPackageFile Include="abc.txt">
    <PackagePath>mycontent/$(TargetFramework)</PackagePath>
    </TfmSpecificPackageFile>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Basically I activate this when I set the PackAsComponent property in my project.
This preserve the "dotnet pack" functionality 100% without the need to specify any parameter.

Comment: Yep this is for advanced scenarios. Needs a lot of understanding for MSBuild but once you master it you can make a lot of it.  Good job.

Answer (score 8):

I was looking for this answer and was annoyed when I couldn't find an obvious one. The solution that worked best for me was to create a nuspec, add the list of DLLs I wanted in the nupkg to that spec and then build with dotnet pack. I created an easy sample and readme here  - [nuget sample app](https://github.com/glennsills/nustuff)

Comment: This approach works for me too (as does Ian Kemp's - I tried them both).  To me it feels like a more "proper" way to do it than Ian's answer - you don't have to explain to anybody what all the stuff in the `.csproj` file is for.  Having the information about the dependencies in the .`nuspec` file feels like a more natural place for it.

Comment: This approach worked for me in the case where I need more control inside the package. just note that having `<NuspecFile>./relative/path/to.nuspec</NuspecFile>` in `<PropertyGroup>` in `.csproj` allows us to use `dotnet pack` command with the `.nuspec` file.

Answer (score 0):

As I've installed Octopus build tools on my build system I use `octo pack` to create the packages. Although this is basically the same thing as just calling good old `nuget.exe`.

https://octopus.com/docs/packaging-applications/create-packages/octopus-cli

Comment: I assume the behaviour is different though? Otherwise Octo wouldn't help the OP? Your answer should probably try to explain what functional different Octo has which solves the OP?

Comment: Yes, to my understanding the "oldschool" tools octo.exe and nuget.exe would basically just zip the bin/debug folder, add some metadata and name the file ".nupkg". However, I don't understand the question in this thread anymore anyway. To achieve what OP is asking, would one not just run `dotnet publish` with dotnet cli these days?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the suggested solution proposed by [Ian Kemp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70345) could not work because adding PrivateAssets="all" to my ProjectReference would remove it from the `<dependencies>` of my package.

I also tried the solution of [GlennSills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902920/glennsills) to define a .nuspec file but then I had to manually maintain the `<dependencies>` section.

The most optimal solution to me was to define everything in the .csproj (no .nuspec). So, I made something like [Ian Kemp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70345) but I don't need to add PrivateAssets="all".

Here is what I needed to add to my .csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>$(TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput);CopyProjectReferencesToPackage</TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <Target Name="CopyProjectReferencesToPackage" DependsOnTargets="BuildOnlySettings;ResolveReferences">    
    <ItemGroup>
      <BuildOutputInPackage Include="$(OutputPath)MyReference.dll" TargetPath=""/>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

This solution works great with the `dotnet pack` command.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34976203)

Answer (score -5):

I hope this will help you.

`nuget pack yournuspecfile.nuspec -properties Configuration=Release -IncludeReferencedProjects`

or your command whatever.