# Add dependencies of reference projects to NuGet package

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package, dotnet-cli

I'm using `dotnet pack` command for creating a NuGet package for the following scenario:

The projects structure:

```
Project B
|----> Project A

Project A
|----> SomePackage
```

I want to create a single NuGet package the contains `ProjectB.dll`, `ProjectA.dll`, and `SomePackage` as NuGet package dependency.

In order to include `ProjectA.dll` as part of the NuGet package (and not package dependency), I used the following solution that suggests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59893520/7122901).

In `ProjectB.csproj`:

```
  <ProjectReference Include="ProjectA.csproj" PrivateAssets="all"/>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>$(TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput);CopyProjectReferencesToPackage</TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
  <Target Name="CopyProjectReferencesToPackage" DependsOnTargets="BuildOnlySettings;ResolveReferences">
    <ItemGroup>
      <!-- Filter out unnecessary files -->
      <_ReferenceCopyLocalPaths Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths->WithMetadataValue('ReferenceSourceTarget', 'ProjectReference')->WithMetadataValue('PrivateAssets', 'All'))"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <!-- Print batches for debug purposes -->
    <Message Text="Batch for .nupkg: ReferenceCopyLocalPaths = @(_ReferenceCopyLocalPaths), ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.DestinationSubDirectory = %(_ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.DestinationSubDirectory) Filename = %(_ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.Filename) Extension = %(_ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.Extension)" Importance="High" Condition="'@(_ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)' != ''" />

    <ItemGroup>
      <!-- Add file to package with consideration of sub folder. If empty, the root folder is chosen. -->
      <BuildOutputInPackage Include="@(_ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)" TargetPath="%(_ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.DestinationSubDirectory)"/>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

**The issue:**

When I run `dotnet pack ProjectB.csproj` I'm getting a single package the contains ProjectA.dll and Project B.dll, but **without a dependency to `SomePackage`**.

**The question:**
How do I add the dependency to `SomePackage` to `ProjectB` NuGet package?

**Possible solutions:**

1. Manually add a package reference from ProjectB to `SomePackage`.
2. Create `ProjectB.nuspec` file and manually add the dependency to `SomePakcage`.

The disadvantage of the 2 approaches: I will need to add the dependency for every NuGet package that `ProjectA` use, which is very easy to forget and breakable.

Answer (score 2):

You have used `PrivateAssets="all"` for **Project A** which means that its transitive dependencies are private and cannot be access by the main **Project B**. We usually use it to disable the dependencies of referenced projects.

**So** if you use that, you cannot get the transitive dependencies from the referenced projects. And it will make **Project A** as a assembly dll and will make it lose the ability of nuget package and its transitive dependencies.

If you still want to achieve the goal, you should note these:

**1)** directly copy the transitive dependencies like `PackageReference` node from Project A's csproj into Project B's csproj.

```
 <PackageReference Include="SomePackage" Version="*.*.*" />

   ......
```

**In this case**, you do not have to use `ProjectB.nuspec` or nuget package manager UI.

**2)** Give up using `PrivateAssets="all"` for **Project A** and make Project A as a nuget package. Ensure the integrity of its nuget features.

Apart from this, there is no other way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to use `PrivateAssets="all"` because I need to create only single NuGet package with all the project references and all the package dependencies.
Option 1 is the same as I mentioned, the big disadvantage that in my case the example is more complex, I have more project reference with ~20 package references from the all the project references, which mean a lot of manual work + very easy to forget dependency and create faulted NuGet package (Can be detected only in runtime)

Comment: + You are correct that option 2 is also a good solution, but I don't want to expose to my users all the project reference as NuGet packages, I need only a single NuGet package.

Comment: Sure. To solve it, you have to directly copy the `PackageReference` node of referenced `Project A` into `Project B`. After all, `Project A`, the middle bridge, has lost its Nuget feature, so you must add its dependency nodes to `Project B`. In order to do that, you have to do this.

Comment: That why I look for an easy solution to add all the dependencies automatically like the solution that copy all the project references dlls. If I had a list of all the NuGet dependencies of all the project references, this could help.

Comment: Directly copy the `PackageReference ` node from Porject A into Project B, and then it will automatically install the nuget packages at one time on Project B,

Comment: As I mentioned before, the only problem with it, that if someone adds another dependency to project A in the future, without adding it to Project B, we will get a faulted NuGet package that only on runtime we will get an exception for MethodNotFound or something like this. This solution is very breakable.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the info. Hum. I am not sure if there is a function to realize that. Maybe not. In the follow-up, you can use `Manage Nuget packages for Solution`. Right-click on the solution-->`Manage nuget packages for Solution`. This will let the nuget package be installed both on the two projects.