# Creating a Nuget package containing only a reference assembly from an existing project which has internal references

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, nuget

I'm working on a plugin-based app where external DLL's are being loaded dynamically. My goal is to create a Nuget package which defines a set of interfaces to be used by the plugins, in the form of a reference assembly (without implementation details).

The problem is, that the project I have to pack (let's call it `ProjectA`) as a Nuget is within a huge solution and has a reference on an another project (`ProjectB`). `ProjectA` contains the interfaces and method calls to `ProjectB` which is doing the actual business logic. My idea is to have the plugin loaded into the memory, and during runtime the actual implementation of `ProjectA` will do the job.

`ProjectA`'s project file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
     <PropertyGroup>
          <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>
          <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild> 
          <ProduceReferenceAssembly>true</ProduceReferenceAssembly> 
          <ProduceReferenceAssemblyInOutDir>true</ProduceReferenceAssemblyInOutDir>
          <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
          <VersionPrefix>1.0.6</VersionPrefix>
     </PropertyGroup>

     <ItemGroup>
          <ProjectReference Include="ProjectB.csproj" />
     </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

When I'm pushing the generated Nuget package from the `bin` folder, the Nuget server shows that the package has a dependency on `ProjectB` and when the third-party project (`ProjectX`) tries to restore it, an error
`Unable to find package ProjectB.` is being thrown which makes sense, because `ProjectB` is not a Nuget package.

`ProjectX`'s project file:

```
...
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="ProjectA" Version="1.0.6" />
    </ItemGroup>
...
```

Question: How to publish `ProjectA` as a Nuget package properly while having an internal dependency which should be hidden from the plugins?

Comment: seems like you want to include dependencies on your nuget package, does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40396161/include-all-dependencies-using-dotnet-pack