# Pack single Nuget with references to other projects

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-7.0, pack

I have a .NET 7 solution with multiple projects. I would now like to pack a Nuget of one project that will serve as a proxy for another application to call some API's. My project structure is similar to:

- Project 1: Infrastructure

  - Enums
- Project 2: Proxy

  - Interfaces
  - Services
- Project 3: API contracts (input/output models)
- Project 4: API's

I would like to pack a Nuget for Project 2 which basically contains services calling the API's available in Project 4. My services return the output models coming from Project 3 after having done the required HTTP call.

Unfortunately when I pack Project 2 and implemented it in another application, I got the error saying `Unable to load one or more of the requested types.\r\nCould not load file or assembly 'xxx.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.` which of course is because there are some enum values referenced in the API contracts project.

Initially I had the same issue with the reference to Project 3 and I could fix it by exposing that project as a Nuget as well. And now I have the feeling I should do the same for Project 1, but I am a bit wary of doing so because eventually I will need to expose my entire solution in Nuget packages and they would never have any value as a stand-alone package.

So is there a way to expose just one single Nuget that encapsulates Project 2 + the required external dependencies (such as the relevant API contracts or the Enums) rather than packing one with 2 other Nuget dependencies?

Comment: NuGet packages are designed to use package references to other NuGet packages. You *can* manually embed multiple DLLs in a package if you write the nuspec by hand, but that isn't the expected usage. If you use dll references (rather than package references) in something that you ship as a NuGet package: expect trouble.

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes but so basically there is no issue if you have a crap architecture in your solution and keep everything in one single project. But if you split your solution into several projects you need to expose them all? That sounds weird to create a Nuget that will contain just 2 enum classes or so.

Comment: Are you using `dotnet pack`? Have you checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59893520/2501279)? See also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64583406/2501279).

Comment: "That sounds weird to create a Nuget that will contain just 2 enum classes or so." - It sounds weird to create a dll that will contain just 2 enum classes or so ... :shrug:

Answer (score 1):

Usually what do we do is this kind of scenarios :

1. Pack your `Infrastructure` as independent `nuget` package.
2. Install that package in your `Proxy` and publish your project as a `nuget`.

There are other ways to include your `dlls` as resources and `Nuget` will just pack them - but in my opinion that is bad practice.

Comment: Yes but so my Proxy nuget will have 1 dependency which is the Infrastructure Nuget. And the Infrastructure Nuget would be available as a standalone Nuget as well which I would like to avoid (having people install just that one would not make sense). And it still feels like an overkill to create a package for just a couple of enums in this case as I would filter the files packed. But like you say, I also feel like the other solutions are bad practice.

Comment: Does it makes sense for them to be separated then ?  I know that when we build ana API Client nuget package we have one nuget that would have all dtos (models, enums) that are needed in API Client nuget. So in that way we would only need to generate 2 nuget packages.  In that case API endpoints returns DTO's - which are mapped from Domain models.

Comment: @J.Memisevic, but what if I need DTOs in several projects, each of which should be delivered as nuget package? In that case I have to have separate project with DTOs. However, this utility project is not needed in the nuget directory.

Comment: Well if that is the case - then yes. But in all project that I saw all the API DTO's are in one csproj which represent contracts of what are requests and responses from API - and they are not used anywhere else expect inside the API project (Everything is mapped in those DTO). That gives you the power of control over the contracts and consumers only do the update of your package when you introduce changes.