# How to dotnet pack all project dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

When using `dotnet pack`, there is not an easy way for me to pack all the references. Is there something easier or am I missing something?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>X</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Y</authors>
    <description>Lib</description>
    <frameworkAssemblies>
      <frameworkAssembly assemblyName=".NETStandard" targetFramework="net8.0" />
    </frameworkAssemblies>
    <dependencies>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework="net8.0"></group>
    </dependencies>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Release\net8.0\Asp.Versioning.Abstractions.dll" target="lib\net8.0" />
    <file src="bin\Release\net8.0\Asp.Versioning.Http.dll" target="lib\net8.0" />
    <file src="bin\Release\net8.0\Asp.Versioning.Mvc.ApiExplorer.dll" target="lib\net8.0" />
    <file src="bin\Release\net8.0\Asp.Versioning.Mvc.dll" target="lib\net8.0" />
    <file src="bin\Release\net8.0\AWSSDK.CognitoIdentityProvider.dll" target="lib\net8.0" />
    <file src="bin\Release\net8.0\AWSSDK.Core.dll" target="lib\net8.0" />
    <file src="bin\Release\net8.0\AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup.dll" target="lib\net8.0" />
    <file src="bin\Release\net8.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.dll" target="lib\net8.0" />
    <file src="bin\Release\net8.0\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions.dll" target="lib\net8.0" />
    <file src="bin\Release\net8.0\Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.dll" target="lib\net8.0" />
    <file src="bin\Release\net8.0\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.dll" target="lib\net8.0" />
    <file src="bin\Release\net8.0\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.dll" target="lib\net8.0" />
    <file src="bin\Release\net8.0\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.dll" target="lib\net8.0" />
    <file src="bin\Release\net8.0\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.dll" target="lib\net8.0" />
    <file src="bin\Release\net8.0\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll" target="lib\net8.0" />
  </files>
</package>
```

I need the following dependencies, since they are in my `.csproj` file and I want to include them without needing to install it again in a separate project. This works, but it's hard to manage.

I also tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59893520/12351801 but it didn't work out for me.

How can I include them automatically without all the hassle? If I want to install another nuget package, I need to add it again in my .nuspec file.

Comment: I believe that all these came into your project as nuget dependencies. Why not use [dotnet pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package-dotnet-cli) command on your `csproj` instead of manually crafting the nuspec file? It will automatically enumerate all your dependencies under the [`<dependencies>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#dependencies-element) section.

Comment: why would you pack them without need to install them ?

Comment: I use dotnet pack in my csproj file, which has a dependency to another class lib which uses the nuget packages, however I don't see it as a dependency

Comment: Why would I pack a package without the necessary dependencies? If someone else wants to consume my package, he needs to install all the dependencies manually, should be automatic right?

Comment: Show your csproj file please.